# In JIRA, is there any option to visualize the work load of a resource in gantt format?

Tags: jira, add-on, jira-plugin, gantt-chart

I have multiple resources in our team assigned to different sprints and projects. The above visualization will help to manage their tasks based on their workload.

Is there any built in report/add-on available in JIRA that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are several that might do what you want. Look at Tempo and BigPicture. Both can provide Gantt chart views. Portfolio for Jira also may do what you want